# pom.xml is not picking the variable from settings.xml

Tags: xml, maven, settings

My pom.xml is not picking variables from the settings.xml.

Below code , which i have specified in my settings.xml

```
<profile>
      <id>compiler</id>
<activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
      <properties>
        <jdk_1.7>C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_45</jdk_1.7>
        <jdk_1.6>C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_29</jdk_1.6>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

after that i have given the profile id in my active profile like

```
<activeProfile>compiler</activeProfile>
```

then i have put this JDk in mypom.xml .below is the code

```
<properties>
            <jdk>${jdk_1.7}</jdk>
            <maven.compiler.argument.source>1.7</maven.compiler.argument.source>
            <maven.compiler.argument.target>1.7</maven.compiler.argument.target>
            <envClassifier>JDK1.7</envClassifier>
</properties>
```

after this also my pom.xml is not picking this jdk_1.7 variable from settings.xml.

if i run this code then i am getting this below error

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-parseable settings C:\apache-maven-3.2.3\conf\settings.xml: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...<properties>\r\n\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd <j... @137:11)  @ C:\apache-maven-3.2.3\conf\settings.xml, line 137, column 11
```

can someone help me?

Comment: there are unprintable character in your Settings.xml befor <jdk_1.7>

Comment: This is not about: Maven not picking up setting. It is about an error in your settings file, look at the exception: in line 137, column 11 you potentially made something `Non-parseable`, check the XML syntax

Comment: there is nothing unprintable character.the line 137 in my settings.xml is <jdk_1.7>C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_45</jdk_1.7>

Comment: can you try to run from console `mvn help:all-profiles` you should see the `compiler` profile in the list coming from `(settings)` and enabled. That would be a first check. Then remove it and try to see if you get the error again, then continue troubleshooting based on this step by step approach

Comment: You shouldn't use properties for differernt JDK's you should use toolchain to handle that...Furthermore you shouldn't change the installation settings.xml better use the user settings.xml for this...

Comment: khmabaise , by maven toolchain plugin , can i use a pom.xml for different JDK like JDK6 and jDk7?

Comment: A_Di-matteo , with mvn help:all-profiles , i am getting the same error which i given in my question.